# Is there a way to opt-out of mixpanel calls when using Stripe checkout.js?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, mixpanel

I'm using the Stripe [checkout.js](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) library (custom configuration) to tokenise credit cards and store them on a Customer before later using them to make payments.

I've noticed during testing that the library attempts to make various calls to `api.mixpanel.com`.

My browser is blocking these calls because I am running [uBlock origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin).  The Stripe library works fine without these calls - so they appear to be just user tracking.

Can I opt out of this?  Either in the Stripe account settings or with some flag to the Stripe library?

---

**EDIT**
As of 2018-02-07, the checkout.js library no longer appears to be making calls to mixpanel.

Comment: I don't see an option to disable it in the source code, but I'd overwrite the track function after loading the stripe library, so ```mixpanel.track = function(){}``` that way you're just overriding it